# While loading Huge amount of Data in table use ngFor , web application is freezed

Tags: javascript, typescript, html-table, angularjs-directive, ngfor

I have Load Huge(1000 above) data in table used ngFor , while loading time web Apllication is freezed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f3L0.png)

1.I have try trackBy function in ngFor. But it's not work.

2.cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport this is repeated same data's while scroll to see that much of data not work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtbgy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpDHT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.